# Calculation of digits in 10^9 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to find the lcm of two numbers and for one of the input cases (28851539 and 1183019) my program returns a negative value . Apparently it is not able to compute (28851529*1183019)/9 .

```
#include <iostream>
long long gcd(int a, int b) {
long long int temp;
if(a%b==0)
{
  return b;
}
else
{
 temp=a%b;
 return gcd(b,temp);
}
}
long long lcm(int a, int b , int g) {
//std::cout<<g;
long long int f=(a*b)/g;
return f;
}

int main() {
long long int a, b;
std::cin >> a >> b;
long long int g = gcd(a,b);
long long int q=lcm(a, b, g);
std::cout << q << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

How do i compute that accurately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is

```
long long int f=(a*b)/g;
```

since all of the types in `(a*b)/g` are `int` then this will be calculated as an `int` and if an `int` is 16 or 32 bits then it will [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Do note that since you have signed types this is actually [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  To get around this you either need to make `a`, `b` or `g` a `long long int` or you can change the parameters of the function to make them all `long long int`s.

```
long long int lcm(long long int a, long long int b , long long int g)
```

I would also suggest you use an `unsigned long long int` if you are not dealing with negative numbers.  If you are not then you can use the type `uint64_t` from `<cstdint>` otherwise `int64_t` to make the type names shorter.

Comment: Thank you that was of great help .

Comment: I would just add this [link on Integer Overflow...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: @c650 Thanks for the link.  I reworded that sentence as I did not like it and included the link.

Comment: @NathanOliver *sentence; and thankful people give upvotes :P